# paypal REST API - flow experience's Pay Now option confusion

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I am writing a proof of concept integration to PayPal using the current REST API and Java SDK. I have already set up the test application and so forth, including the client ID and secret.

My goal is to have the user leave my site, then come back to my site having fully processed their payment on PayPal's side - requiring no further interaction on our part besides capturing the payment ID.

I am using the payments API and corresponding Payment DTO: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/

I am also using the payment experience API: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payment-experience/#definition-flow_config

I create the Payment via payment.create(APIContext), then scrape the approval_url out of the resulting DTO's links and redirect to that URL. In the PayPal sandbox, I log in with my test buyer account. I am shown the "Pay Now" button with all of my order details, and I click on the "Pay Now" button. I get redirected back to my specified redirect URL, but when I use postman to examine the Payment associated with the paymentID URL parameter the state for it is "created" when I expect it to be "approved". Furthermore, when I log in as my test buyer I do not see an update to my PayPal balance, nor do I see a transaction in my test merchant account.

When I used Postman to execute the Payment, the transaction showed up on my test merchant account and the balance of my test buyer account decreased.

I thought that if I specified user_action=commit in the FlowConfig for the web profile I attach to my Payment, it would mean that I would not need to go through the separate step of actually executing the payment once I come back from PayPal.

From the API reference on the FlowConfig:

> Set user_action=commit. Redirects the buyer to the PayPal payment page, which shows the Pay Now button. When the buyer clicks Pay Now, the payment is processed immediately.

Does "payment is processed immediately" not equate to "approve and execute the payment"? Is there an additional option that I am missing, or am I misunderstanding the Pay Now option?